# How to find the name the folder of the current activeTextEditor in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

This will find the current **workspace** folder of the current `activeTextEditor`:

```
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor
if (!editor) {
  vscode.window.showInformationMessage('editor does not exist')
  return
}

const path = editor.document.uri.fsPath
const workspaceFolder = vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(editor.document.uri)
```

How to find the **folder** of the current `activeTextEditor` (file)?

Comment: I have not experimented with the vs code extensions.. but this might be helpful: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const path = require('path');

let dirname = path.dirname(editor.document.uri.fsPath);
```